# Terraform eks module - workers custom tags

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I want to have 2 worker groups, each with custom tag. 
For example, if I use this template - https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/v4.0.2/examples/basic/main.tf

```
 worker_groups = [
{
  name                          = "worker-group-1"
 ....
  //here - what I want to have
  tags = {selector=wg1}
},
{
  name                          = "worker-group-2"
  ....
  //here - what I want to have
  tags = {selector=wg2}
},
```

I see the input variables in https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/v4.0.2/variables.tf , lines 115-122
and template - https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/v4.0.2/workers.tf , lines 19-29,
but I can't understand how to properly configure them to get custom tags on workers.

Comment: Documentation shows how to do this: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks#usage-example

Comment: yes, it shows, but it doesn't work(at least with the provided template example)

Comment: Ok, but your provided code in the question conflicts with the documentation, so does the question differ from your implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found where it was implemented and the [example](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/pull/252/commits/062c229affeefbbebe9d527319e5bbca63d567e6) how to use it:

```
worker_groups = [
{
  name                          = "worker-group-1"
 ....
},
{
  name                          = "worker-group-2"
  ....
},
]

// and here comes the tags block
worker_group_tags = {
  worker-group-1 = [
    {
      key   = "k1"
      value = "v1"
      key                 = "k2"
      value               = "v2"
      propagate_at_launch = true
     },
   ],
   worker-group-2 = [
     {
       key   = "k3"
       value = "v3"
       key                 = "k4"
       value               = "v4"
       propagate_at_launch = true
     },
   ],
 }
```

Comment: I tried using you labeling error and go a terraform puting it in locals didn't have an effect. did you manage to label a node?

Answer (score 2):

The current version has changed slightly:

```
worker_groups = [
{
  name = "worker-group-1"
  ....
  
  tags = [
    {
      key                 = "k1"
      value               = "v1"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
    {
      key                 = "k2"
      value               = "v2"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    }
   ] 
}]
```